# How does docker calculates the time to show the result of health condition of a container?

Tags: docker

Here are the commands that I used for reference:

```
docker run -dt --name tmp --health-cmd "curl -f http://localhost" busybox sh
docker ps
docker ps
docker ps
```

After few minutes, docker ps will show "health as unhealthy".

The default healthcheck options are these:

```
--interval=DURATION(default:30s)
--timeout=DURATION(default:30s)
--start-period=DURATION(default:0s)
--retries=N(default:3)
```

So, how is the time calculated here? Any idea?

Possible solutions:

3*30s=90s. But it's just my guesswork.